# Capybara visit method throws wrong number of arguments error

Tags: rspec, capybara

After upgrading my Rails app to Ruby 3 I started to see this error when running integration tests.

```
  1) User visits Dam without a permitted role
     Failure/Error: visit '/'
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:44:in `handshake'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/driver.rb:39:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:58:in `new'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:58:in `for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.35.3/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:83:in `browser'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.35.3/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:104:in `visit'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.35.3/lib/capybara/session.rb:278:in `visit'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.35.3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:53:in `call'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.35.3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:53:in `visit'
     # ./spec/system/rain_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried a few variations inside the test using byebug (inserted just before the visit call) and I'm seeing a really strange issue, where it gives the arguments error even if I give it the number of arguments it asks for in the error message:

```
(byebug) page.visit('/')
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

nil
(byebug) page.visit
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

nil
(byebug) visit('/')
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

nil
(byebug) visit
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

nil
(byebug) page.method(:visit).owner
Capybara::Session
```

I also noticed that if I commented out the visit call and let the test run the following line containing a `fill_in` method, I got a very similar error message.

I did upgrade some gems but the possibly relevant ones -- factory_bot*, kaminari*, nokogiri, rspec* -- only increased maximum 2 minor versions. I didn't upgrade Capybara at all. I did change bundle and ruby versions, see this excerpt from the diff from my Gemfile.lock:

```
 PLATFORMS
-  ruby
+  x86_64-linux

...

 RUBY VERSION
-   ruby 2.7.6p219
+   ruby 3.1.2p20
 
 BUNDLED WITH
-   2.1.4
+   2.3.10
```

The visit method worked fine before upgrading. Any idea what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace you can see that the issue isn't the parameters being passed to `visit`, it's happening inside the Selenium handshake method at `# /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:44:in` handshake'`

If you look at the selenium-webdriver changelog you'll see that Ruby 3 really isn't supported until selenium-webdriver v4, so if you want to use Ruby 3 you'll need to update selenium-webdriver and capybara to the latest versions and, if you're registering your own driver, update your driver registration for selenium v4 compatibility